# Is "dscl" available on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

Is `dscl` available on OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)?

I'm trying to figure out before I can make a choice between the desktop and the server editions.

Comment: There is no server "edition", it's a program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `dscl` is available on OS X Mountain Lion.

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html) only exists for 10.7.4, but it's there on 10.8 as well.

Note that there is no dedicated "Server edition" of OS X Mountain Lion. You just add [OS X Server](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/) to your existing OS X installation by [buying it from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id537441259?ls=1&mt=12) (currently it's priced at $19.99).

Answer (score 0):

dscl is available, but it [does not necessarily work as you might expect](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4185006?start=0&tstart=0) from earlier versions. For instance, using it to add hostname aliases does no longer work. At least when using the standard desktop version of OS X, without the server addition. Scripts for adding users might also need to be changed to accomodate changes in 10.8.